# Collapse button disappears when sidebar is expanded in Experience Builder

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-experience-builder

I configured a sidebar containing an table widget to be collapsible in an Experience Builder application and set it to be collapsed by default. When I open the app in a browser, the collapse button works fine in collapsed mode, but then disappears when I expand the sidebar, preventing me from collapsing it again. How can I prevent this from happening?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Solved this one on my own: The issue was caused by the second (empty) pane being too small, which caused cropping of the collapse button in the first pane. Dragging the boundary of the empty pane farther out away from the first pane solved the problem.